# Css not applying in fancybox on a plugin

Tags: jquery, yii, fancybox

I am using yii tokeninput plugin [Yii tokeninput](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/tokeninput/) for autocomplete. If i am using it on a page its css is appliying but if i am using it in fancybox than css is not applying.

controller Code

```
echo $this->renderPartial('profile/_user_message',array('model'=>$saveMessage),false,true);Yii::app()->end();
```

View Code

```
<?php 
       $prePopulate = null;
       $processPrePopulate = false;
       if($prePopulate)
               $processPrePopulate = true;

       $this->widget('ext.tokeninput.TokenInput', array(
       'model' => $model,
       'attribute' => 'TARGET_USER_IDS',
               'url'=>$this->createUrl('user/search'),
       'options' => array(
           'allowCreation' => false,
           'preventDuplicates' => true,
          // 'resultsFormatter' => 'js:function(item){ return “<li><p>” + item.name + “</p></li>” }',
           'theme' => 'facebook',
                       'prePopulate' => $prePopulate,
                       'processPrePopulate' => $processPrePopulate,
       )
   )); ?>
```

Comment: fancy box does not do anything special . does it show `css` effect without fancybox? and please we can not guess the code implementation you did for css application

Comment: please share some come code and is css without fancybox working? and how do you display in fancybox? renderpartial?

Comment: share the code what ever you have so that we can see where is the problem. You have to apply css in view file not controller

Comment: 4 upvotes in 45 minutes?

Comment: have you tried passing false to 3rd and 4th parameter in renderPartial

Comment: @afnan: yes i already tried  that

Comment: at present you are not using FancyBox in above example so i guess styles are getting applied in posted example

Comment: I guess the php code is irrelevant here. You either show the rendered html and your js code or show a link, which would be easier to debug with firebug

Comment: As @JFK alludes to, this is most likely a non-PHP issue.  Sounds like we need to see the CSS and the rendered HTML to see the order in which the CSS files are sourced as well as the way classes and ids are assigned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toleninput extension include css file in any page automatically but it is not include css file in fancybox i don't know what the reason behind it so i include that css file in its parent page it solved my problem.

```
$assetUrl =Yii::app()->getAssetManager()->publish(Yii::getPathOfAlias('ext.tokeninput.assets'));
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile($assetUrl.'/css/token-input-facebook.css');
```